# RSpec crashing Rails on require rails_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, rspec

I get a segmentation fault whenever I have used `require "rails_helper"` in a spec and the following is code:

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe "List players" do
  it "displays first name and last name of players saved" do
    player1 = Player.create(first_name:"Michael",last_name:"Jordan")
    player2 = Player.create(first_name:"Lonzo",last_name:"Ball")
    visit "/"
    expect(page).to have_text("Michael")
    expect(page).to have_text("Jordan")
    expect(page).to have_text("Lonzo")
    expect(page).to have_text("Ball")
    expect(page).to have_link("New Player")
  end
end
```

When I run rspec, I get the segmentation fault with the following dump:

```
<internal:trace_point>:346: [BUG] Segmentation fault at 0x0000000000000008
ruby 2.7.0p0 (2019-12-25 revision 647ee6f091) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

-- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
c:0048 p:0003 s:0258 e:000257 METHOD <internal:trace_point>:346
c:0047 p:0016 s:0254 e:000252 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/debug-1.6.2/lib/debug/session.rb:129 [FINISH]
c:0046 p:---- s:0249 e:000248 CFUNC  :eval
c:0045 p:0026 s:0241 E:000638 BLOCK  /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:5 [FINISH]
c:0044 p:---- s:0237 e:000236 CFUNC  :catch
c:0043 p:0004 s:0233 E:000668 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:4
c:0042 p:0105 s:0228 e:000227 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:208
c:0041 p:0022 s:0216 e:000215 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:184
c:0040 p:0018 s:0206 e:000205 BLOCK  /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:154 [FINISH]
c:0039 p:---- s:0202 e:000201 CFUNC  :each
c:0038 p:0005 s:0198 e:000197 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:152
c:0037 p:0025 s:0192 e:000191 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:19 [FINISH]
c:0036 p:---- s:0188 e:000187 CFUNC  :each
c:0035 p:0063 s:0184 e:000183 CLASS  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:18
c:0034 p:0007 s:0181 e:000180 CLASS  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:7
c:0033 p:0019 s:0178 e:000177 TOP    /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:6 [FINISH]
c:0032 p:---- s:0175 e:000174 CFUNC  :require
c:0031 p:0258 s:0170 e:000169 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32
c:0030 p:0029 s:0160 e:000159 TOP    /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0029 p:---- s:0157 e:000156 CFUNC  :require
c:0028 p:0258 s:0152 e:000151 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32
c:0027 p:0032 s:0142 e:000141 BLOCK  /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74 [FINISH]
c:0026 p:---- s:0137 e:000136 CFUNC  :each
c:0025 p:0042 s:0133 e:000132 BLOCK  /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69 [FINISH]
c:0024 p:---- s:0126 e:000125 CFUNC  :each
c:0023 p:0026 s:0122 e:000121 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58
c:0022 p:0013 s:0117 e:000116 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174
c:0021 p:0036 s:0112 e:000111 TOP    /mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/config/application.rb:7 [FINISH]
c:0020 p:---- s:0109 e:000108 CFUNC  :require_relative
c:0019 p:0005 s:0104 e:000103 TOP    /mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/config/environment.rb:2 [FINISH]
c:0018 p:---- s:0101 e:000100 CFUNC  :require_relative
c:0017 p:0039 s:0096 e:000095 TOP    /mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/spec/rails_helper.rb:4 [FINISH]
c:0016 p:---- s:0092 e:000091 CFUNC  :require
c:0015 p:0098 s:0087 e:000086 METHOD /usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72
c:0014 p:0005 s:0071 e:000070 TOP    /mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/spec/features/listing_players_spec.rb:1 [FINISH]
c:0013 p:---- s:0068 e:000067 CFUNC  :load
c:0012 p:0007 s:0063 e:000062 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2115
c:0011 p:0023 s:0054 e:000053 BLOCK  /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1615 [FINISH]
c:0010 p:---- s:0049 e:000048 CFUNC  :each
c:0009 p:0018 s:0045 e:000044 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1613
c:0008 p:0036 s:0041 e:000040 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102
c:0007 p:0007 s:0035 e:000034 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86
c:0006 p:0065 s:0029 e:000028 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71
c:0005 p:0020 s:0021 e:000020 METHOD /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45
c:0004 p:0025 s:0016 e:000015 TOP    /var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/exe/rspec:4 [FINISH]
c:0003 p:---- s:0013 e:000012 CFUNC  :load
c:0002 p:0112 s:0008 E:001690 EVAL   /usr/local/bin/rspec:23 [FINISH]
c:0001 p:0000 s:0003 E:000ee0 (none) [FINISH]

-- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
/usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
/usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:71:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:86:in `run'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:102:in `setup'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1613:in `load_spec_files'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1613:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1615:in `block in load_spec_files'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2115:in `load_file_handling_errors'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/rspec-core-3.11.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:2115:in `load'
/mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/spec/features/listing_players_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:72:in `require'
/mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require_relative'
/mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
/mnt/c/Code/Rails/tdd2/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler.rb:174:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:58:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `block in require'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:69:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/bundler/runtime.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara.rb:7:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.13.0/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:32:in `require'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:6:in `<main>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:7:in `<module:Capybara>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:18:in `<class:Config>'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:18:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/capybara-3.37.1/lib/capybara/config.rb:19:in `block in <class:Config>'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:152:in `def_instance_delegators'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:152:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:154:in `block in def_instance_delegators'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:184:in `def_instance_delegator'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable.rb:208:in `_delegator_method'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:4:in `_valid_method?'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:4:in `catch'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:5:in `block in _valid_method?'
/usr/lib/ruby/2.7.0/forwardable/impl.rb:5:in `eval'
/var/lib/gems/2.7.0/gems/debug-1.6.2/lib/debug/session.rb:129:in `block in initialize'
<internal:trace_point>:346:in `instruction_sequence'

-- Machine register context ------------------------------------------------
 RIP: 0x00007faa081c3494 RBP: 0x000055992ed23fc0 RSP: 0x00007ffe4a257678
 RAX: 0x0000000000012007 RBX: 0x00007faa078867d8 RCX: 0x00007faa083054f0
 RDX: 0x0000000000002007 RDI: 0x0000000000000000 RSI: 0x000055992cdcac60
  R8: 0x00007faa083054f0  R9: 0x000055992cdcac60 R10: 0x0000000000000000
 R11: 0x000055992cdcac60 R12: 0x00007faa07985590 R13: 0x000055992bfda220
 R14: 0x000055992c110b30 R15: 0x00007faa07985590 EFL: 0x0000000000010206

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa08302639) [0x7faa08302639]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa0830286c) [0x7faa0830286c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa0817c39b) [0x7faa0817c39b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa0827f8dd) [0x7faa0827f8dd]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(0x7faa07f28090) [0x7faa07f28090]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_iseqw_new+0x4) [0x7faa081c3494]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082eb057) [0x7faa082eb057]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_invoke_proc+0x1f6) [0x7faa082f3886]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_proc_call_with_block+0x51) [0x7faa08236a91]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa08303100) [0x7faa08303100]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa08303566) [0x7faa08303566]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa0830365f) [0x7faa0830365f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_exec_event_hooks+0x72) [0x7faa08304622]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e4436) [0x7faa082e4436]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f3061) [0x7faa082f3061]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082fbc7a) [0x7faa082fbc7a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e6b3c) [0x7faa082e6b3c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_catch_obj+0x30) [0x7faa082e6c50]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e95e1) [0x7faa082e95e1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_yield+0x271) [0x7faa082fcf81]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_ary_each+0x3c) [0x7faa0810452c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e95e1) [0x7faa082e95e1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_yield+0x271) [0x7faa082fcf81]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_ary_each+0x3c) [0x7faa0810452c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e95e1) [0x7faa082e95e1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c9203) [0x7faa081c9203]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_require_string+0x27) [0x7faa081ca807]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c9203) [0x7faa081c9203]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_require_string+0x27) [0x7faa081ca807]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_yield+0x271) [0x7faa082fcf81]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_ary_each+0x3c) [0x7faa0810452c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e95e1) [0x7faa082e95e1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_yield+0x271) [0x7faa082fcf81]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_ary_each+0x3c) [0x7faa0810452c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e95e1) [0x7faa082e95e1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c9203) [0x7faa081c9203]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_require_string+0x27) [0x7faa081ca807]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c9203) [0x7faa081c9203]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_require_string+0x27) [0x7faa081ca807]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c9203) [0x7faa081c9203]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_require_string+0x27) [0x7faa081ca807]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c9833) [0x7faa081c9833]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c99db) [0x7faa081c99db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f284c) [0x7faa082f284c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_yield+0x271) [0x7faa082fcf81]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_ary_each+0x3c) [0x7faa0810452c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e95e1) [0x7faa082e95e1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c9833) [0x7faa081c9833]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081c99db) [0x7faa081c99db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e54b5) [0x7faa082e54b5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082f22db) [0x7faa082f22db]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082d8806) [0x7faa082d8806]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa082e956a) [0x7faa082e956a]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(rb_vm_exec+0x1d2) [0x7faa082efcf2]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(0x7faa081805f1) [0x7faa081805f1]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.7.so.2.7(ruby_run_node+0x4e) [0x7faa0818545e]
ruby2.7(0x55992bdd317f) [0x55992bdd317f]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf3) [0x7faa07f09083]
ruby2.7(_start+0x2e) [0x55992bdd31ce]

-- Other runtime information -----------------------------------------------
...
```

What am I getting wrong? How do I fix this?